# Infinite loop with a graphql and mongoose backend

Tags: express, react-hooks, graphql, apollo-client

I have a backend made in express and mongoose:
all my mutations and queries work perfectly except one mutation sends me an infinite loader

```
updateVehicleVerification: async (_, { id, updateVehicleVerification }) => {
  const vehicleVeri = await VehicleVerification.findById(id);
  if (!vehicleVeri) {
    throw new Error(ErrorMessage + ' : Verification de Vehicule');
  }

  await VehicleVerification.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    updateVehicleVerification
  );
  const veri = await VehicleVerification.findById(id);
  return veri;
},
```

And the query I use here:

```
export const UPDATE_CONTROL_VEHICLE = gql`
  mutation updateVehicleVerification(
    $id: String!
    $updateVehicleVerification: VerificationVehicleInput
  ) {
    updateVehicleVerification(
      id: $id
      updateVehicleVerification: $updateVehicleVerification
    ) {
      honk {
        state
        image
        comment
      }
      mileage
      dateVerification
      stateVehicle {
        damaged
        good
        missing
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I I solved the problem !
I did not manage the case where the data reached me by the request which keyed an infinite loop.

Comment: Can you please post the solution code for future users?